# Using Memcached in PHP with Homebrew - OS X

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to use Memcached in PHP with Homebrew. Installation was succeesfull, but when I tried to run php in cl I've got this error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcache.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcache.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcache.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcache.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>   Laravel development server started on http://dev-local.ilikeq.com:8000
>   [Fri Apr 25 21:15:48 2014] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcache.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcache.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>   [Fri Apr 25 21:15:48 2014] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

My brew list:

- autoconf
- beanstalk
- freetype
- gettext
- jpeg
- libevent
- libmemcached
- libpng
- mcrypt
- memcached
- mhash
- php55
- php55-mcrypt
- php55-memcache
- php55-memcached
- php55-mongo
- unixodbc
- zlib

My brew config:

- HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
- ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
- HEAD: 127a89a32fc2f6fe758e8cbf1d74f92e5819c55e
- HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
- HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
- CPU: quad-core 64-bit ivybridge
- OS X: 10.9.2-x86_64
- Xcode: 5.1.1
- CLT: 5.1.0.0.1.1396320587
- Clang: 5.1 build 503
- X11: 2.7.5 => /opt/X11
- System Ruby: 1.8.7-358
- Perl: /usr/bin/perl
- Python: N/A
- Ruby: /Users/Singularity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rub

Comment: did you ever figure out what was the problem here? I'm struggling with the same problem.